# Fluentd not writing logs into amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, fluentd

I am trying to test the fluentd-s3-plugin yet at the moment it is not posting my logs into s3 bucket.
I am running everything on ubuntu xenial, having installed fluentd with td-agent.
The following is the td-agent log file located at */var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log*

```
 2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: reading config file path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: starting fluentd-0.12.26
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-config-placeholders' version '0.4.0'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-plaintextformatter' version '0.2.6'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kinesis' version '1.1.1'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-mongo' version '0.7.13'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '1.5.5'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '0.6.8'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-scribe' version '0.10.14'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '0.10.28'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td-monitoring' version '0.2.2'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '0.4.2'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '0.12.26'
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: adding match pattern="nginx.log" type="s3"
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: adding source type="tail"
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    type tail
    format nginx
    path /var/log/nginx/access.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/nginx-access.pos
    tag nginx.log
  </source>
  <match nginx.log>
    @type s3
    s3_bucket kd.creatives
    aws_key_id xxxxxx
    aws_sec_key xxxxxx
    s3_region us-west-2
    path logs/
    buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/s3
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M
    utc 
    format_json true
    include_time_key true
    buffer_chunk_limit 256m
  </match>
</ROOT>
2016-09-23 09:16:18 -0300 [warn]: parameter 'format_json' in <match nginx.log>
  @type s3
  s3_bucket kd.creatives
  aws_key_id xxxxxx
  aws_sec_key xxxxxx
  s3_region us-west-2
  path logs/
  buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/s3
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M
  utc 
  format_json true
  include_time_key true
  buffer_chunk_limit 256m
</match> is not used.
2016-09-23 09:16:20 -0300 [info]: following tail of /var/log/nginx/access.log
2016-09-23 09:16:25 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:25 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:25 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:25 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:26 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:26 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:26 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:26 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:26 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:26 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:26 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:26 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:27 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:27 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:27 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:27 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:27 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:27 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:27 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:27 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 612 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
2016-09-23 09:16:28 -0300 [warn]: pattern not match: "172.17.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:16:28 +0000] \"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1\" 404 571 \"http://localhost:10241/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36\" \"-\""
```

Also here is my *td-agent.conf* file

```
    # Centralized nginx logs into Amazon s3
<source>
    type tail
    format nginx
    path /var/log/nginx/access.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/nginx-access.pos
    tag nginx.log
</source>

<match nginx.log>
    @type s3
    s3_bucket xxxxxxx
    aws_key_id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    aws_sec_key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    s3_region us-west-2

    path logs/
    buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/s3
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d%H%M

    utc

    format_json true
    include_time_key true
    buffer_chunk_limit 256m
</match>
```

I would really appreciate any answer on why fluentd is not posting the logs into s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks in_tail failed to parse your nginx log.
So, fluentd didn't send all log to s3.
`format nginx` treats Combined Log Format as default.

I think you need to use custom format to parse your nginx log.

```
<source>
    type tail
    format /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)" "(?<forwarder>[^\"]*)")?/
    time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    path /var/log/nginx/access.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/nginx-access.pos
    tag nginx.log
</source>
```

Ref.  http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail

You can test your own regex by fluentd-ui.
http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/fluentd-ui

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just starting with fluentd and now I have got used to the log regex format (same as ruby).